# javascript immediately invoked function

Tags: javascript, object, module

Hi friends I got doubt after seeing below code. I know below code is creating an object and assigning to app variable. but what is the use of use all parameter. Can anybody will help me to understand, what it does and what is the benefit. please share if there is any useful link.

```
var app = (function (app, $) {

}(window.app = window.app || {}, jQuery)));
```

Comment: Would you like to get module pattern understanding, or you have some practical issue to clearify?

Answer (score 1):

It takes window.app and jQuery from your global scope and injects them into your function. It's a neater way of doing this:

```
var app = function(app, $)
{

}

app(window.app = window.app || {},jQuery);
```

The benefits of this is that you are creating your own scope. Any javascript you put into this function will not be in the global scope. This can prevent variables being overridden etc.

Comment: ok, is there any article or blog post regarding this. I want to understand perfectly.

Comment: I think this explains what you're asking in more detail: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

Comment: Thanks. it is a very useful post.